# MTMR AppleScript not activating

Tags: json, applescript

```js
{
    "type": "staticButton",
    "align": "left",
    "width": 44,
    "image": {
      "base64": "D0...HBV424njnde"
  },
  "action": "appleScript",
  "actionAppleScript": {
    "inline":
      "tell application \"Google Chrome\"\rset minimized of window 1 to true\rend tell"
    },
},
```

So this is my Code for a MTMR button. When i press the Button Chrome is supposed to minimize. But nothing is happening. I tested the script in the Apple Script editor and it worked perfectly. I also gave MTMR the required Permissions. So I have no idea what is wrong. Here is the link to MTMR: https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the tick in Chrome 
View -> Developer -> Allow Javascript from AppleScript